# How do I add support for the 'chrome' namespace to my Vite config?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, svelte, vite, web-extension

I'm using Vite and Svelte to develop a Chrome extension, and during `build` I received warnings like:

```
3:43:06 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] /home/mike/Code/myapp/components/Component.svelte:50:18 
'chrome' is not defined
```

I understand what these warnings mean (`chrome` isn't normally part of the browser environment) and the warnings to not affect the compiled output, however I would like to fix the warnings.

I've [done some research](https://dev.to/michmich112/writing-chrome-extensions-using-svelte-kit-and-manifest-v3-mkd/comments) and checked [the Svelte docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration) and while other people are having the same issue, there doesn't seem to be a fix at present.

My `svelte.config.js` is simply:

```
import sveltePreprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

export default {
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
};
```

Any my `vite.config.ts`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      stream: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream",
      events: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events",
      assert: "assert",
      crypto: "crypto-browserify",
      util: "util",
      "node-fetch": "just-use-native-fetch",
    },
  },
  define: {
    "process.env": process.env ?? {},
  },
  build: {
    target: "es2020",

    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [nodePolyfills({ crypto: true })],
      output: {
        globals: ["chrome"],
      },
    },
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: [],
    },
    minify: isMinifiying,
    emptyOutDir: false,
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    disabled: false,
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
      },
      plugins: [NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({ buffer: true })],
      target: "es2020",
    },
  },
});
```

**How do I add support for the 'chrome' namespace to Vite config?**

Comment: Have you installed the type definitions `npm install --save @types/chrome`?

Comment: @lamplightdev Good question! Yes I have (since before I asked the question)